# Error in parsing my Json input containing Instant Date type

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, resttemplate

`` Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String "2019-07-22 08:09:45": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-07-22 08:09:45' could not be parsed at index 10; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String "2019-07-22 08:09:45": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-07-22 08:09:45' could not be parsed at index 10 ``

The Json being returned is

```
{
   "job":"Foo",
   "time":"2020-02-12 18:33:23"
}
```

I am using **RestTemplate** to call some other service, but every time the above exception pops up giving Date error. I have tried configuring `ObjectMapper` for `RestTemplate` but still the same issue.

Below is the code snippet I am using to configure RestTemplate.

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter createMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(createObjectMapper());
        return converter;
    }
```

PS : Pojo Structure (Can't edit for this use case as POJO's are in commons).

```
String job;
Instant executionTime;
```

Comment: Did you try using a POJO to parse the JSON ?

Comment: The expected [string format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) for parsing to an Instant is different from the string shown in the question. How are you using your RestTemplate?

Comment: @andrewjames added rest template usage.